# Fushion charts pie3d not working properly on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, ruby

I am using fushion charts for getting pie 3D effect, where the back end used is ruby and front end is angular.

Its working fine. But,sometimes pie chart data is getting over lapped and it is showing as below.

[image]

Below given is what we need.And it has been worked before.

[image]

We are referring this site https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/?chart=pie3d for fushion charts.

In our angular js html page we used the command

```
<div fusioncharts 
    width="100%"         
    type="pie3d"
    datasource="{{pieDataSource}}">
</div>
```

And we pass the values from our angular js controller as

```
  $scope.pie_chart_options      = 
                                {
                                theme: "fint",
                                // caption: "Matches",
                                decimals: "0",
                                showlabels: "0",
                                showlegend: "1",
                                legendShadow: "0",
                                plottooltext: "$label: $value",                                    
                                legendBgColor: "#ffffff",
                                slicingdistance: "15",
                                showHoverEffect: "1",
                                animateClockwise: "1",
                                legendBorderAlpha: "0",
                                showpercentvalues: "0",
                                enablemultislicing: "1",
                                legendItemFontSize: "10",
                                legendItemFontColor: "#666666",                                    
                                showpercentintooltip: "0",
                              }
```

Please help me  how to handle with this issue.

Comment: Add more details about the implementation and links to library etc.

Comment: I am not sure about the full implementation but it seems like you are not passing the right data, from expected figure it looks like percentages of all colors should not exceed more than 100% but in actual figure it appears that is not the case, yellow color alone is covering around 100%

Comment: I have edited my question. can you please check it.